# Continuously JNLP pods are getting failed on kubernetes engine

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jnlp

I'm running a Jenkins in Kubernetes Engine and it connects to JNLP slave pods when a job triggers, this was working successfully previously, but those JNLP pods are failed to start with following error nowadays.

```
state:
      terminated:
        containerID: docker://6a9af6be55bfee1ebc15cbd29b4fd053e30f8e9692f1e46121501dba5c13b04a
        exitCode: 127
        finishedAt: 2018-09-07T06:01:03Z
        message: |
          oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"jenkins-slave\": executable file not found in $PATH"
        reason: ContainerCannotRun
        startedAt: 2018-09-07T06:01:03Z
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is your pod template definition? have you added a `jnlp` container to it?

Comment: @csanchez I'm using Kubernates Jenkins plugin with Kubernetes pod template to download the jenkins-slave pods soon after a job is triggered.

Comment: what is your pod template definition?